# V-for Array Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to go through this array of objects but I have no idea how to do it with v-for, when using this syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(data,index) in userStore.links">{{data.link}} - {{index}}</li>
</ul>
```

Result: data.link = nothing and index = link <== i dont understand this
But if i use this

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="data in userStore.links">{{ data[0].link }}</li>
</ul>
```

Results: google.com <=== Thats okay, if i can increment 0 in 1 is good.

Structure:

```
[ { "_id": "63f3db204ea92c071e2fe24c", "link": "hola.com", "shortLink": "7HG2zM6", "uid": "63e1314aa27f02c4b630c1a6" }, { "_id": "63f3dccb4ea92c071e2fe251", "link": "adios.com", "shortLink": "FsSuAwo", "uid": "63e1314aa27f02c4b630c1a6" }, { "_id": "63f3e1394ea92c071e2fe256", "link": "hola.gg", "shortLink": "0K8aRWz", "uid": "63e1314aa27f02c4b630c1a6" } ]
```

[image]

[image]

I need help if I can do it differently or how to increase the array index when going through it. I just need to show the whole object. Thank you

Output all the array

Comment: Sounds like each entry in your `userStore.links` array is also an array. Perhaps you want a nested loop. Or maybe you want to flatten the array. Only you actually know what your data structure looks like

Comment: I added in my question

Comment: Is that the structure of `userStore.links`? If so, your first code should work fine ~ https://jsfiddle.net/eaw6vxnr/

Comment: yeah, buts dont work xd

Comment: I add 2 images you can see

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: All the info like : links and id =id: "63f3db204ea92c071e2fe24c", "link": "hola.com"

Answer (score 0):

Axios returns a proxy of the object, then when you go through it you need an index, then I have solved it by equalizing,

```
links = res.data ==> Now links=res.data.links
```

now this works with v-for without problems.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(data,index) in userStore.links">{{data[index].link}} - {{index}}</li>
</ul>
```

That way if userStore.links is an array, it will iterate through all items.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-an-object

Comment: It does not work because index, it is not a number I do not know why, index = link, that's why I get an error because it does not find it